# Mono - Flux switchIfEmpty and onErrorResume

Tags: spring, mono, spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux

In project reactor is it possible to implement a stream with `switchIfEmpty` and `onErrorResume` at the same time?

```
infoRepository.findById(id); //returns Mono<Info>
```

in case of `empty or error then switch to the same backup stream`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no *single* operator that does these things together, but you can trivially switch to an empty publisher on an error, then handle both cases through `switchIfEmpty` like:

```
infoRepository.findById(id)
              .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty())
              .switchIfEmpty(newPublisher);
```